# Making a table with filtered drop downs based on other columns values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook  where I'm creating multiple unique lists to be used in drop downs for a table. Here's some sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

All of the lists are a set of unique values from a column in a table. Some of the drop down options are dependent on the values from other drop downs in the same row. I've used the code below to create the unique lists to be used for the drop downs (starting with unique regions):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,Table1[Region])=0),Table1[Region])
```

and this to make the list countries for the specific region:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(((COUNTIF($B$1:B1,Table1[Country]))+($N$6<>Table1[Region]))=0),Table1[Country])
```

and this to make the list of sites from a specific country from a specific region:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(((COUNTIF($C$1:C1,Table1[Site]))+($N$6<>Table1[Region])+($O$6<>Table1[Country]))=0),Table1[Site])
```

I then select the cells to be shown in the drop down using the Name Manager for each case:

```
=Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$12,LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$12<>""),ROW(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$12)-1))
```

Finally, I apply a data validation referencing the lists stored in Name Manager to the necessary cells to create the drop downs.

I have the structure working for just a single row, but I am having trouble applying it to an entire table since the unique indexed lists are being created based on a single cell's value (in this case N6 and O6). How would I be able to apply this dynamically so that each row in a given table is what's generating the initial lists?

Comment: First, if you have `Office365` then it is really simple to achieve your scenario. Some sample data with your formulas is helpful to get help here.

Comment: Just updated with a snippet of sample data. I wasn't sure how to paste it raw in a table format.